# How can I select an <a> tag that has a sibling <ul> tag after it in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

HTML is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub menu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Menu 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I select an `<a>` tag that has a sibling `<ul>` tag after it, with pure CSS?

(Which, in the example above, will be `<a>Menu 2</a>`.)

Comment: Basically with pure CSS you can't. You could do it if the `<a>` came after the `<ul>`, but not the way you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don’t think you can.

- CSS 2 includes the [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), which allows you to select an element that immediately follows another element.

  E.g. `a + ul` would select your `<ul>` containing the text “Sub menu 2”
- CSS 3 includes the [general sibling selector (`~`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), which allows you to select an element that follows another element, even if there are elements in between them.

  E.g. `a + ul` would select your `<ul>` containing the text “Sub menu 2” even if there was a `<span>` between the `<a>` and the `<ul>`

But neither has a selector that lets you select an element which has specific elements *following* it.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly via nth-child

```
ul li:nth-child(2) a { color:#009; }
```

Selects the second list item, then subsequent anchor tags.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/yF3Mz/1/)

Comment: Nope, please read the question. Select A that have sibling UL.

Comment: @GusDeCooL THis allows you to select the anchor.. but there is no method to select parent elements with CSS. So the answer is -- with pure CSS you can't or you have to specify the anchor specifically.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a jsFiddle file you can reference [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/keghK/)

**CSS**

```
ul > li > a {color:red}

ul > li > ul  {color:blue}​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub menu 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Menu 1</a>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: This selects the `Sub menu 2` item and the OP wants to select the `Menu 2` item.